# Unable to sync to ubuntu one with non-sudo user?

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one

My computer is running under Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and I use Ubuntu One in order to sync my data.

All this stuff work fine with my main account (which is, by the way, part of the sudo users group).

On the other hand, I can't use Ubuntu One on another user of my computer (**not** part of the sudo users group).

Here is the result of `u1sdtool --status` with this second user session :

```
State: READY
connection: Not User With Network
description: ready to connect
is_connected: False
is_error: False
is_online: False
queues: WORKING_ON_METADATA
```

When I try to open the Ubuntu One client GUI, I'm asked a password to unlock a keyring (which is impossible since this user is not sudo user, right?).

I need a hand on this one, please...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There are Ubuntu SSO credentials in the [gnome-keyring](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring):

> GNOME Keyring is a collection of components in GNOME that store secrets, passwords,
> keys, certificates and make them available to applications.
>
> GNOME Keyring is integrated with the user's login, so that their secret storage
> can be unlocked when the user logins into their session.

In your case, probably, passwords from gnome-keyring and shadow file are not the same. I.e. this is not an sudo issue.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I'm not sure to understand it. What should I do ? Delete the keyring and create a new one with exactly the same password of my user ? Thanks

Comment: Login as another user, launch seahorse (Passwords and Keys) and change password for "login" keyring.

Comment: Thanks for your help, nab. You were right, both passwords were not identical. Now they are. I have still the issue, although...